# python order of evaluation of lhs and rhs of multiplication

Tags: python

Will the order of execution of the LHS and RHS of a python operator (such as multiplication) be in reading order? Equivalently is the code below guaranteed to calculate 30?

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = 0
while x:
    result += len(x) * x.pop()
assert 4**2 + 3**2 + 2**2 + 1**2 == result
print(result)
```

If the `len(x)` is executed after the `x.pop()` the result will not be 30.

I'm not so much interested in the answer for particular implementations of Python, more whether the language has guarantees on the order of evaluation.

Comment: I assume you have tried it yourself, so the question is just whether the language spec guarantees this behaviour, not whether this *is* the behaviour?

Comment: Yes @kaya3, that's what I was trying to get to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is guaranteed to evaluate to 30.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

> **6.16. Evaluation order**
>
> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.